# How to customize the way XCode displays and edits .txt files

Tags: xcode

**EDIT:**  I fixed this particular situation by changing the .txt file to .cpp but just not building it with the rest of the project.  Silly me.  I'm still curious if there's a way to do this generically.

Is there a way that I can change how XCode displays .txt files?  I'm working with OpenGL and am writing my vertex and fragment shaders in .txt files then reading those files into my code.

I want XCode to do things like auto indent functions and display keywords in certain colors.  I included a screenshot of what it looks like now, with a .txt file next to a .cpp file.

[image: A .txt file next to a .cpp file in XCode]

Alternatively is there a different file extension I could use instead of .txt?  (I'd rather not switch IDE's.  I'd just really like auto indent and colored keywords; auto-completing variables/functions is a nice feature but not necessary.)  I'm reading in the file with this function:

```
std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }
    return ("failure reading in txt file");
}
```

Comment: If it is cpp why don't you make it a cpp file?

Comment: @matt The file won't compile if it's a .cpp file because it's written in GLSL not C++.  I might be able to switch the GLSL .txt file to .cpp if I don't include it in my project build... but regardless I've wondered how to do this in other situations.

Comment: Right... darn. You could open it in a dedicated GLSL editor program...